# Unable to connect to secure website using mechanize in Python

Tags: python, urllib2, mechanize, httplib

I'm trying to open a secure (https) website using mechanize library in Python. When I try to access the website, the server closes the connection and exception BadStatusLine is raised.

I have tried to modify the headers using the `addheaders` property, but no response.

```
import mechanize

br = mechanize.Browser()
print 'opening page ...'
resp = br.open('https://onlineservices.tin.nsdl.com/etaxnew/tdsnontds.jsp')     #this one works fine
print 'ok'

print 'opening page 2 ...'
resp = br.open('https://incometaxindiaefiling.gov.in/portal/index.do')          #exception raised 
print 'ok'
```

Exception:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>       pydev_imports.execfile(file, globals, locals) #execute the script   File "Z:\pyTax\app_test.py", line 22, in 
>       resp=br.open('https://incometaxindiaefiling.gov.in/portal/index.do')
>   File "build\bdist.win32\egg\mechanize_mechanize.py", line 203, in
>   open   File "build\bdist.win32\egg\mechanize_mechanize.py", line 230,
>   in _mech_open   File "build\bdist.win32\egg\mechanize_opener.py",
>   line 188, in open   File "build\bdist.win32\egg\mechanize_http.py",
>   line 316, in http_request   File
>   "build\bdist.win32\egg\mechanize_http.py", line 242, in read   File
>   "build\bdist.win32\egg\mechanize_mechanize.py", line 203, in open
>   File "build\bdist.win32\egg\mechanize_mechanize.py", line 230, in
>   _mech_open   File "build\bdist.win32\egg\mechanize_opener.py", line 193, in open   File
>   "build\bdist.win32\egg\mechanize_urllib2_fork.py", line 344, in _open
>   File "build\bdist.win32\egg\mechanize_urllib2_fork.py", line 332, in
>   _call_chain   File "build\bdist.win32\egg\mechanize_urllib2_fork.py", line 1170, in https_open   File
>   "build\bdist.win32\egg\mechanize_urllib2_fork.py", line 1116, in
>   do_open   File "D:\Python27\lib\httplib.py", line 1031, in getresponse
>       response.begin()   File "D:\Python27\lib\httplib.py", line 407, in begin
>       version, status, reason = self._read_status()   File "D:\Python27\lib\httplib.py", line 371, in _read_status
>       raise BadStatusLine(line) httplib.BadStatusLine: ''

Comment: mechanize probably tries to connect with an ssl protocol version which is refused/not supported by the server.

Comment: your code works fine on my computer, does this only occour when accessing this specific website only or does it happen with others too?

Comment: this problem occurs only with specific website, other websites work fine with same code. this website perfectly opens in browsers.

Answer (score 0):

`httplib.BadStatusLineis` s a subclass of `HTTPException`. Raised if a server responds with a HTTP status code that we don’t understand. That's whats causing your problem. I am not entirely sure about the fixup though, as your code works fine on my computer.